# Registering an Azure Bot on https://dev.botframework.com/

Tags: azure, botframework

Unfortunately the site https://dev.botframework.com/ doesn't see my bot, that was created in Azure. I followed this steps:

1. Go to the https://dev.botframework.com/bots
2. Click on Create a bot with the Azure Bot Service
3. Create Web App Bot
4. I use the Azure Subscription, where i have an Owner Role.

Now i have the Bot, i could test it, i could modify code using my Desktop Visual Studio, i could publish the code from the visual studio to the Bot and test it in Azure

But the site https://dev.botframework.com/bots/ still shows me, that I don't have any bots.

I am completely new to this topic, so could you help me on this, what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: You should be using https://apps.dev.microsoft.com  dev.bot.. is being retired

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The dev.botframework.com site is (being) retired and is being replaced with the Azure Bot Service. The bot you created should appear on Azure Bot Service inside the Azure portal instead of on the Botframework portal.

Answer (score 0):

You can get started through this link
https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/services/bot-service/
For the official documentation, you can visit
https://docs.botframework.com/en-us/azure-bot-service